# A HiveQL query with an output for each one hour of the day

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to write a HiveQL query that returns a number of equipements each time an event `/live//activate` occurs and that for each one hour of the day. Here is how my table looks like:

[image]

The issue is that I have to  change and rewrite  my query 24 times according to each intervall of one hour.

For example if I want the number of equipements between 4:00 AM and 5:00 AM the query I write is:

```
SELECT count(equipement) FROM parcours_fin WHERE event=' /live//activate' AND `date` BETWEEN ' 2018-01-26 04:00:00' AND ' 2018-01-26 05:00:00';
```

If you have any idea about a query that allows me to get the number of equipements for each one hour of the day, instead of rewriting my query 24 times, I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT count(equipement) FROM parcours_fin WHERE event=' /live//activate' AND `date` BETWEEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('',"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.sss"),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:00:00.000') AND from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('',"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.sss")+3600);
```

Edit :

```
SELECT count(equipement) FROM parcours_fin WHERE event=' /live//activate' AND `date` BETWEEN date_format(unix_timestamp(), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:00:00.000') AND date_format(unix_timestamp()+3600, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:00:00.000')
```

Edit 2 :

```
SELECT count(equipement) FROM parcours_fin WHERE event=' /live//activate' AND `date` BETWEEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(unix_timestamp(),"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.sss"),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:00:00.000') AND from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(unix_timestamp(),"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.sss")+3600);
```

Edit 3 (working solution):

```
SELECT count(equipement), date_format(`date`, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:00:00.000 aa") 
FROM parcours_fin WHERE event=' /live//activate' 
group by date_format(`date`, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:00:00.000 aa") ;
```

Comment: I'm sorry but which method I will pass to it the two lines?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, i thought it was an hibernate question, i will delete my answer

Comment: I already have a hive table for equipements each second. I have just to run a hive query

Comment: i searched a bit, can you try this query ?

Comment: try the second one please

Comment: It gives me the following error: 

    Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10016]: Line 1:106 Argument type mismatch 'unix_timestamp': date_format only takes STRING_GROUP, DATE_GROUP types as 1st argument, got LON

Comment: Thank you very much,thanks to you query I get the result I am showing in my response . Still one issue instead of hours I am having a NULL value

Comment: There is an other issue wich is the query gives just 17 result from 2018-01-26 01:00:00.000 to 2018-01-26 12:00:00.000 it does not give me for the rest hours of the day (From 13h to 00h)

Comment: You are right, this format does not make the distinction between AM and PM ... give me a minute

Answer (score 0):

you can perform this using group by. I would suggest add the date information to the group by as well to get this by day.  the following query get the counts per hour for each day, you can add an extra clause to the where condition to filter by day

```
SELECT count(equipement), hour(`date`), date_format(date`, "yyyy-MM-dd")    
FROM parcours_fin WHERE event=' /live//activate' 
group by hour(`date`), date_format(date`, "yyyy-MM-dd") ;
```

Comment: The query gives me the number of the equipement gouped by   `date_format(date`, "yyyy-MM-dd")` for each day and none for `hour(`date`)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output I am getting:

[image]

Comment: can you paste some sample data ? specially for your field "date", probably it is not in a proper format to get the hour directly from it .

Comment: In the future, additional to that it would be useful show your table creation

Comment: When I run the query  `SELECT  hour(`date`) , `date`  
FROM parcours_clients_fin WHERE event=' /live//activate' ;` it gives me 
   _c0  date
        [12  2018-01-26 12:14:49]
 [18  2018-01-26 18:34:45]
 [19  2018-01-26 19:18:11]
 [7  2018-01-26 07:23:43]

Comment: i do not see any issue with your time format (just run select hour('2018-01-26 19:14:49 2');),  can you update your question with your table definition and data sample? it would be useful to replicate the problem. can you paste here the query that you are running as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use full join with all 24 hours to get records for each hour.

Demo:

```
select count(equipement) cnt, h.hr hour
from

(--replace with your query
select 1 as equipement, hour('2018-01-26 04:00:00' ) as hr --calculate each record hour for the join
) your_table
full join --join with all 24 hours
        (select stack(24,
                      0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23
                     ) as hr
        )h on your_table.hr=h.hr  
group by h.hr;
```

Output:

```
OK
cnt      hour
    0       0
    0       1
    0       2
    0       3
    1       4
    0       5
    0       6
    0       7
    0       8
    0       9
    0       10
    0       11
    0       12
    0       13
    0       14
    0       15
    0       16
    0       17
    0       18
    0       19
    0       20
    0       21
    0       22
    0       23
    Time taken: 83.921 seconds, Fetched: 24 row(s)
```

Data for every hour is calculated. It was the only record with data in my example, for hour=4, it was shown in the result.

Comment: Thank you for response. I get the same result as yours even with my data